# Implementation an authentication scheme for mobile apps using Tastypie

Tags: android, python, ios, django, tastypie

I would like to create a REST service with authentication for mobile devices. This is the first time I will be doing something like this, so I would like to receive some advise on how I would implement things.

For this I would need to create a signup form which let's the user signup for the services. 
I see no issue here I can just post the form data to the server and let it return a response.

If the form is valid a new user object will be created and immediately be logged in. Also a API KEY will be generated using:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from tastypie.models import create_api_key

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)
```

The request, will return a 301 HTTP status and contain a redirect URI to fetch the API KEY.

After this step the app will request another URI (the URI received in the 301 response of the signup request) to access the API KEY (I will be using Tastypie's [ApiKeyAuthentication](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#apikeyauthentication) scheme). The request will contain the session cookie received in the previous request response, this way to view will be secured and I will be able to user the login_required decorator.
The response will be plain JSON with username and api key.

These values will be stored somewhere in the app.

Any requests now made will add the username and API KEY stored in the app so further requests will be more secure.

Does this look like a good scheme to follow ? Are there holes in the design ?